# How to modify error logs in google cloud functions?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am using google cloud functions with Python. I want to format all logs with some additional data, e.g. customer id. I achieved this without any problem using Stackdriver Logging library with `CloudLoggingHandler`. In the same manner, I also like to add this information to uncaught error logs and tracebacks.

I tried to modify `sys.excepthook` and `sys.stderr` but it did not work, probably they are handled exclusively by cloud functions.

Is there any way I can modify uncaught exceptions or modify handled errors, e.g. by using Stackdriver error reporting? Or do you have any alternative solution for this (without catching all exceptions)?

Comment: Just to clarify, your uncatched exception are logged in the stackdriver logging part but you want to log as ERROR these uncatched exceptions to automatically have an entry in error reporting, isn't it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No, I already have errors in error reporting. I want to change format of the logs from uncaught exceptions in logging.

Comment: Have you had the opportunity to examine this article in the Cloud Functions docs?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting#functions-errors-log-python    It appears to show that Google's recipe for handling exceptions in Cloud Functions is to trap RuntimeError.  I realize you explicitly said you didn't want to catch all exceptions ... I'm illustrating that catching all exceptions is what Google's example seems to show.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions provides the (currently) highest level abstraction for code execution.  The philosophy is that your bring the code that implements your desired logic and Cloud Functions provides the highest level environment for execution.  This has pluses and minuses.

Furthermore, the biggest plus is that you have the very least to concern yourself with in order to get the execution you desired.

On the other hand, you have very little in the way of operational control (the vision is that Cloud Functions provides the maximum in operational control).

As a consequence, if you want more control over the environment at the cost of you having to do more "work", I suggest you Cloud Run. In Cloud Run, you package your application logic as a Docker container and then ask it to take care of all execution of such logic.  In your container, you can do anything you want ... including using technology such as Stackdriver logging and defining a CloudLoggingHandler.  Cloud Run then takes care of your scaling and execution environment from there.

To sum up, the answer then becomes "No" you don't have control over error logs in Cloud Functions but you can achieve your desired outcome by leveraging Cloud Run instead.

Comment: Are you sure that I cannot reach to uncaught exceptions or their logs in any way? That would be nice if we could do it in cloud functions, but I don't plan to use Cloud Run just for this.

Comment: Howdy @merdogan ... Am I sure?  Nope.  I'm not even sure what day it is most days :-) ... However, I still hold by my previous thinking.  There are "tiers" to infrastructure access with Cloud Functions being the highest and Compute Engines being the lowest.  With Cloud Functions, the deliberate goal is to do as much of the work as possible on your behalf and, in many ways "protect you from yourself".  Cloud Functions provides the incoming request processing and error handling for you ... leaving you to provide what you want to do with a request.

Comment: I have been using cloud functions for a long time and I know what functionalities are available. Using a serverless system doesn't stop you from doing many things. I think there will be an answer to this question. Thanks for your suggestion, and I agree with you that I can do more with cloud run. But my current question is not about which product should I use. I cannot change the product I use right now, so I will wait for a positive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot override sys.excepthook, you might do the following:

To provide a little context, I organize my code structure similar to what is presented here: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/structure-for-google-cloud-functions-development-and-split-multiple-file/

Google stores your function entrypoint function in an env var called `X_GOOGLE_ENTRY_POINT`. You use Python language capabilities to override this function and wrap it similarly to a "decorator", basically wrapping it around a try/except block and then you can run whatever code you want there. I tried using `sys.modules[\__name__]` but it didn't work, so I went for `locals()`.

I have the function code defined in test_logging.py

```py
from app.functions.test_logging import *
```

and after importing I do the following

```py
fn = os.getenv('X_GOOGLE_ENTRY_POINT')
lcl = locals()
def decorate(fn):
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            '''Do whatever you want to do here'''
    return run

lcl[fn] = decorate(lcl[fn])
```

It's hackish, but it's working for me and it's particularly useful because I keep my code base inside functions folder and I basically don't need to touch the main.py, making this very flexible. You can ever re-raise the error after handling the exception if you want to allow the GCP to know it has failed and maybe re-run